# HTML 5 Desktop notification is not working in IE

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, internet-explorer, notifications

I got this code from [HTML 5 desktop Notification](https://github.com/ttsvetko/HTML5-Desktop-Notifications) regarding the desktop notification and was trying to build the same in my application.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang=en>
<head>
    <style>
        html, body {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0%;
            font-family: "helvetica","verdana","calibri", "san serif";
            overflow: visible;
            padding: 0%;
            border: 0%;
        }
    </style>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
    <title>
        Html5 Notification API Example
    </title>
</head>
<body>
    <script>

        (function () {
            var PERMISSION_DEFAULT = "default";
            var PERMISSION_GRANTED = "granted";
            var PERMISSION_DENIED = "denied";
            var PERMISSION_NOTSUPPORTED = "notsupported";

            var PERMISSIONS = [PERMISSION_GRANTED, PERMISSION_DEFAULT, PERMISSION_DENIED, PERMISSION_NOTSUPPORTED];
            var DIRESCTIONS = ["auto", "ltr", "rtl"];

            var IENotificationIndex = -1;
            var IECloseNotificationEvents = ["click", "scroll", "focus"];
            var getIco = function (icon) {
                var lastIndex = icon.lastIndexOf(".");
                return (lastIndex !== -1 ? icon.substr(0, lastIndex) : icon) + ".ico";
            };

            var _Notification = window.Notification || /* Opera Mobile/Android Browser */
                window.webkitNotifications && WebKitNotification || /* IE9+ pinned site */
                "external" in window && "msIsSiteMode" in window.external && window.external.msIsSiteMode() !== undefined && IENotification || /* Notifications Not supported. Return dummy constructor */
                DummyNotification;
            /**
             * @constructor DummyNotification
             */
            function DummyNotification() {
                var dummyElement = document.createElement("div");
                this.addEventListener = function (eventName, callback) {
                    dummyElement.addEventListener(eventName, callback.bind(this));
                };
                this.removeEventListener = function (eventName, callback) {
                    dummyElement.removeEventListener(eventName, callback.bind(this));
                };
                this.dispatchEvent = function (eventName) {
                    if (typeof eventName !== "string") {
                        return;
                    }
                    try {
                        dummyElement.dispatchEvent(new Event(eventName));
                    } catch (e) {
                        var event = document.createEvent("Event");
                        event.initEvent(eventName, false, true);
                        dummyElement.dispatchEvent(event);
                    }
                };
            }
            Object.defineProperty(DummyNotification, "permission", {
                enumerable: true,
                get: function () {
                    return PERMISSION_NOTSUPPORTED;
                }
            });
            Object.defineProperty(DummyNotification, "requestPermission", {
                enumerable: true,
                writable: true,
                value: function (callback) {
                    callback(this.permission);
                }
            });
            /**
             * @constructor IENotification
             */
            function IENotification(title, options) {
                DummyNotification.call(this);
                var notificationIndex = IENotificationIndex;
                Object.defineProperties(this, {
                    close: {
                        value: function (event) {
                            if (notificationIndex === IENotificationIndex) {
                                window.external.msSiteModeClearIconOverlay();
                                // Remove close events
                                IECloseNotificationEvents.forEach(function (event) {
                                    window.removeEventListener(event, this.close);
                                }.bind(this));
                                this.dispatchEvent("click");
                                this.dispatchEvent("close");
                                notificationIndex = null;
                            }
                        }.bind(this)
                    }
                });
                // Clear any previous icon overlay
                this.close();
                // Set icon
                if (this.icon) {
                    window.external.msSiteModeSetIconOverlay(getIco(this.icon), this.description || this.title);
                }
                // Blink icon
                window.external.msSiteModeActivate();
                // Trigger show event
                this.dispatchEvent("show");
                // Attach close event to window
                IECloseNotificationEvents.forEach(function (event) {
                    window.addEventListener(event, this.close);
                }.bind(this));
                // Increment notification index
                notificationIndex = ++IENotificationIndex;
            }
            Object.defineProperty(IENotification, "permission", {
                enumerable: true,
                get: function () {
                    var isTabPinned = true;
                    return isTabPinned ? PERMISSION_GRANTED : PERMISSION_DENIED;
                }
            });
            Object.defineProperty(IENotification, "requestPermission", {
                enumerable: true,
                writable: true,
                value: function (callback) {
                    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
                        if (this.permission === PERMISSION_DENIED) {
                            alert(this.PERMISSION_REQUEST_MESSAGE);
                        }
                        resolve(this.permission);
                    }.bind(this));
                }
            });
            Object.defineProperty(IENotification, "PERMISSION_REQUEST_MESSAGE", {
                writable: true,
                value: "IE supports notifications in pinned mode only. Pin this page on your taskbar to receive notifications."
            });
            /**
             * @constructor WebKitNotification
             */
            function WebKitNotification() { }
            Object.defineProperty(WebKitNotification, "permission", {
                enumerable: true,
                get: function () {
                    return PERMISSIONS[window.webkitNotifications.checkPermission()];
                }
            });
            Object.defineProperty(WebKitNotification, "requestPermission", {
                enumerable: true,
                writable: true,
                value: function (callback) {
                    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
                        window.webkitNotifications.requestPermission(function (permission) {
                            resolve(permission);
                        });
                    });
                }
            });

            if (!_Notification.permission) {
                Object.defineProperty(_Notification, "permission", {
                    enumerable: true,
                    get: function () {
                        return _Notification.permissionLevel && _Notification.permissionLevel();
                    }
                });
            }
            /**
             * @constructor Notification
             */
            function Notification(title, options) {
                var dir;
                var notification;
                if (!arguments.length) {
                    throw TypeError('Failed to construct "Notification": 1 argument required, but only 0 present.');
                }
                
                if (title === "") {
                    title = "\b";
                }
                if (arguments.length > 1 && "object" !== typeof options) {
                    throw TypeError('Failed to construct "Notification": parameter 2 ("options") is not an object.');
                }
                dir = Object(options).dir;
                if (dir !== undefined && DIRESCTIONS.indexOf(dir) === -1) {
                    throw TypeError('Failed to construct "Notification": The provided value "' + dir + '" is not a valid enum value of type NotificationDirection.');
                }
                options = Object(options);
                notification = new _Notification(title, options);
                if (!notification.body) {
                    Object.defineProperty(notification, "body", {
                        value: String(options.body || "")
                    });
                }
                if (!notification.data) {
                    Object.defineProperty(notification, "data", {
                        value: options.data || null
                    });
                }
                if (!notification.dir) {
                    Object.defineProperty(notification, "dir", {
                        value: dir || DIRESCTIONS[0]
                    });
                }
                if (!notification.icon) {
                    Object.defineProperty(notification, "icon", {
                        value: String(options.icon || "")
                    });
                }
                if (!notification.lang) {
                    Object.defineProperty(notification, "lang", {
                        value: String(options.lang || "")
                    });
                }
                /* TODO: noscreen property */
                /* TODO: renotify property */
                if (!notification.requireInteraction) {
                    Object.defineProperty(notification, "requireInteraction", {
                        value: Boolean(options.requireInteraction)
                    });
                }
                /* TODO: sound property */
                if (!notification.silent) {
                    Object.defineProperty(notification, "silent", {
                        value: Boolean(options.silent)
                    });
                }
                if (!notification.tag) {
                    Object.defineProperty(notification, "tag", {
                        value: String(options.tag || "")
                    });
                }
                if (!notification.title) {
                    Object.defineProperty(notification, "title", {
                        value: String(title)
                    });
                }
                if (!notification.timestamp) {
                    Object.defineProperty(notification, "timestamp", {
                        value: new Date().getTime()
                    });
                }
                /* TODO: vibrate property */
                return notification;
            }
            Object.defineProperty(Notification, "permission", {
                enumerable: true,
                get: function () {
                    return _Notification.permission;
                }
            });
            Object.defineProperty(Notification, "requestPermission", {
                enumerable: true,
                value: function () {
                    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
                        var promise = _Notification.requestPermission(function (permission) {
                            resolve(permission);
                        });
                        if (!(promise instanceof Promise)) {
                            return;
                        }
                        resolve(promise);
                    });
                }
            });
            window.Notification = Notification;
        })();

        window.addEventListener("load", c);// register an eventlistener for web page onload
        function init() {
            var b = document.getElementById("but");//get the button object            
            b.addEventListener("click", noti, false);//register an eventlistener for when user clicks the button
        }
        // function called when the web page has loaded
        function c() {
            init();
            if (window.Notification && Notification.permission !== "granted") {//check to see if notification is granted and notification is supported
                //if it is not supported request permission
                Notification.requestPermission(function (status) {
                    if (Notification.permission !== status) {
                        Notification.permission = status;
                    }
                })
            }
        }
        //function called when button is clicked and shows notification
        function noti() {
            if (Notification.permission == "granted") {//check if we have notification permission
                var title = "Just Testing This App";//title for notification
                var options = {//options for notification
                    body: "it is just a test"

                }
                noti = new Notification(title, options);
                

            }
            else {                
                alert("permission not granted");//alert error message : permission is not granted
            }
        }
    </script>
    <button id=but>
        Send Notification Now
    </button>
</body>
</html>
```

And here when i ran this html code in chrome and click on button..i am getting the notification but when i tried to ran the same in IE..it is not showing any notification and also no error is getting thrown by IE. As per instruction from link..they are saying to pinned the site..So attaching the same which i did but no success [image: Pinned Site For IE]

Don't know where i am doing wrong. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Could you create a codepen?

Comment: @fabrv not able to copy paste the code to above mentioned site but you can take the code from my Question and paste in  https://www.w3schools.com/tryit/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_default

Comment: As you can see from [caniuse](https://caniuse.com/notifications) and the [browser compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/notification#Browser_compatibility) table of MDN, IE 11 doesn't support notifications. HTML5-Desktop-Notifications purportedly supports IE, but actually it doesn't. I also find some issues in that repository saying that it doesn't work on IE. I also search a lot and I think it's impossible to support notifications on IE.

Comment: @YuZhou do you have any idea about  other plugin for desktop notification from web app which supports all major browser like IE, Chrome, edge

Comment: I don't think there's a desktop notification plugin across browsers. Because since IE 8, it doesn't allow us to display popup outside current browser. There's no such plugin in IE at least.